# applying pandas groupby on serial number to get the single value from each column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like -

```
SERIAL COUNTRY      GOODS   VALUE
1      AUSTRALIA    NA      NA
1      NA           STEEL   NA
1      NA           NA      PACIFIC
2      NEW ZEALAND  NA      NA
2      NA           STEEL   NA
2      NA           NA      COAL
3      INDIA        NA      NA
3      NA           WOOL    NA  
3      NA           NA     LIMITED
```

I want to group this data frame according to *SERIAL* with values not containing *NA*.

It should look something like this -

```
SERIAL COUNTRY      GOODS   VALUE
1      AUSTRALIA    STEEL   PACIFIC
2      NEW ZEALAND  STEEL   COAL
3      INDIA        WOOL    LIMITED
```

the code that I have written is -

```
new_df =df.groupby(['SERIAL'])['COUNTRY'].apply(lambda x: x if x is not 'NA')
```

I have also tried to make it as a string separated with commas and split them later on but it did not work.

```
df.groupby(['SERIAL'])['COUNTRY'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique().astype(str))).reset_index()
```

can someone please help with this issue, or atleast tell me about the error in my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) if for each group and column is only one non `NaN` value:

```
#if necessary repalce NA to missing values 
df = df.replace('NA',np.nan)
df = df.groupby(['SERIAL'], as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   SERIAL      COUNTRY  GOODS    VALUE
0       1    AUSTRALIA  STEEL  PACIFIC
1       2  NEW ZEALAND  STEEL     COAL
2       3        INDIA   WOOL  LIMITED
```

Another more general solution is per group forward and back fill missing values and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by all columns:
:

```
df = df.replace('NA',np.nan)
df = df.groupby(['SERIAL']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: @MadhurYadav - Do you need first `df = df.replace('NA',np.nan)` ?